# Insert media button will always add into the same tinyMCE editor

Tags: metabox, uploads, media, tinymce, buttons

I have an issue with the insert-media button. I have 2 instances of tinyMCE with both Add Media button. When I add a media in one of the two tinyMCE, all my media will go in this after, whatever which insert-media button I click on.

For instance, if I add a media in my tinyMCE-1 by clicking my media button of tinyMCE-1, it will add my media in it all is good.

But if I now want to add another media in tinyMCE-2 by clicking on media button of tinyMCE-2, it will add on the tinyMCE-1 !

I don't unerstand why at all. I am stuck here for several days. I checked and the activeEditor is tinyMCE-1 when it has to be and same for tinyMCE-2...

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Please show your full code.

Answer (score 1):

As just previously answered, your problem likely simply is that you used the same ID (the 2nd argument for `wp_editor()` multiple times).